# touchescancelled is called instead of touchesended

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview

I'm trying to glow a view on touch and unglow it when touch is ended. While doing this, I noticed that when I raise my finger from the view, `- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` method is not called but instead `- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` method is called on the view. Is that a normal behaviour? I thought `touchesCancelled` is called if touches are cancelled because of a system issue like low memory warning. I did my job by using touchesCancelled but nevertheless I am wondering why it does not properly call `touchesEnded`. Is it a bug?

Comment: This is not normal behavior.  I doubt it is a bug though.  The answer depends entirely on your project.  Nobody can begin to speculate without seeing all relevant portions of code.

Comment: You left out way too much information for this question to be answered. Redo it or toss it out. In the meantime, anyone else who has this problem should look at the view in which they are extracting their touch point. If your touch point data is coming from, say, [touches.anyObject locationInView:touches.anyObject.view], try [touches.anyObject locationInView:[actual reference to view]]. That will fix a whole host of problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you touch that view and raise your finger, you should not drag your finger. If you did like that, then `touchesCancelled:` method will get called. So I think your view is too small to touch. If yes, then make a big View and try it again. It will work for you then.

Consider this as a `comment`..

Answer (score 2):

This is not normal behavior. On raising your finger, touchesEnded should be called.

touchesCancelled should be called when your view is removed during touch or a system event happens (e.g. lock the phone while your finger is touching the screen)

See the documentation for [touchesEnded](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621084-touchesended) and [touchesCancelled](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621116-touchescancelled).

Without your code, it is impossible to tell what is happening. However it seems that even if you manage to get touchedEnded called as it should, you would want to respond to both cases. In swift:

```swift
class MyView: UIView {
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        stopGlow()
    }

    override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        stopGlow()
    }

    private func stopGlow() {
        //Your code here...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like touchesCancelled is called instead of touchesEnded if the touch doesn't move far enough in the first second or so after it begins. If I make a small but quick movement, touchesCancelled will fire because the total movement wasn't big enough; and if I make a small movement slowly, touchesCancelled will fire before the movement is even finished because the iOS gives up on waiting to see if I will move further. Apparently the iOS is making some judgement about how much moving is "significant" and is regarding small movements as cancelled touches.

You can simply call touchesEnded from touchesCancelled if that helps. But in the case of a very quick movement, this won't be called until the timeout period, so there might be a delay between when the movement actually ends and the time that touchesCancelled is fired.

By the way, I've also noticed that if you do a small, quick movement, then lift your finger, then start another movement, before touchesCancelled is fired, that's not considered a new movement and touchesBegan won't fire. This is complicating the handwriting function in my app, since handwriting is all about small, quick movements.

Answer (score 0):

I had a situation where presenting a document window using automatic UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen resulted in a window that could move up and down a little even though it was modal.  It was enough to call touchesCancelled when I moved a sub-view by tracking touches on it's parent view.  If I grabbed the edge of the sub view and moved my finger too quickly, the presented window would move a little and it would cancel the touch, which in turned called touchesCancelled.

Answer (score 0):

You left out way too much information for this question to be answered. Redo it or toss it out. In the meantime, anyone else who has had this problem or some other relating to unexpected behavior related to touchesBegan/Moved/Ended/Cancelled should look at the view in which they are extracting their touch point. If your touch point data is coming from, say, `[touches.anyObject locationInView:touches.anyObject.view]`, use another reference to the view, like `self.view` or some such. That will fix a whole host of problems.